# History of squaring the circle

Tags: geometry, reference-request, math-history

I'd like to know the main attempts in history to prove the squaring the circle. Do you know a good book or link where I can find a schematical and methodical description of the history of this problem? Thank you

Comment: See [Wiki's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle) with references and  Ernest William Hobson,  (1913) [Squaring the Circle: A History of the Problem](https://archive.org/details/squaringcirclehi00hobsuoft) Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Really good advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps, this is the best link I can provide : A video by [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/user/numberphile) 
 - [Squaring the Circle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMP9a2J4Bqw)

[image]

Comment: Really interesting YouTube channel!

Comment: @xyzt I too am big fan of this channel. You must subscribe to it. Their videos are worth watching.

Comment: Well .. sometimes numberphile is mind blowing and sometimes it is just :-( . I would say that for  a short description of Any maths topic numberphile is good. +1

Comment: @Thelonewolfisbackbaby... I read your bio.. did you appear for JEE, or what are your plans? IISC?IISER? I am from Indore,M.P. and in 11th standard.I am also planning to do something in mathematics.

Comment: Well... I will appear for JEE next year ... I m in class 12 right now. Most of my time is consumed in doing maths so iisc will be my first choice.

Comment: How about you ?? Are you preparing for JEE?

Comment: @Thelonewolfisbackbaby... Yes I am. Did you appear for KVPY (I appeared) , it is the best for joining research institute in India.

Comment: Yes.. I did.. but I don't have any intrest in bio and chemistry so I failed... :-P they habe a cutoff of 50+ which I can't get even if I do all the physics and maths questions...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56946/discussion-between-jaideep-khare-and-the-lone-wolf-is-back-baby).

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra Yaaden BC, apan idhar pehli baar mile the.

Comment: :-)  Haa BC...  MSE kaa faayda!!!!

Comment: @Vidyanshu Bhai 10k Hit ho gaye! Nacho BC :)

Comment: Abe saala m abhi yehi dekh ra that dopher m Ki iske 10k hue yaa nhi.... Tb 9973 the... Mjhe LGA bs ek answrr krde..  10 k ho jaegi.... Congo....  Talented h tu. :-P

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra wholesome xD

Answer (score 1):

A classical resource is E. W. Hobson's book [*Squaring the circle. A history of the problem.*](https://archive.org/details/squaringcirclehi00hobsuoft) It was published in 1913, so it is a bit outdated from the viewpoint of historical methodology, but it has the advantage of covering the topic broadly from antiquity to the end of the 19th century. I find it mathematically accurate, and the choice of the episodes analyzed is not trivial (for example, you can find there a fine discussion of the not-so-well known solution given by Descartes). Moreover, Hobson wrote the book only a few decades after the first rigorous proofs of the transcendence of $\pi$, which perhaps explains his interest for the history of the quadrature of the circle. A more recent and very fine study is P. Eymard and J. P. Laffont's book *Autour du nombre $\pi$*. This beautiful book is mathematically more engaging than Hobson's, but well worth reading. I have just realized that there is an [English edition](https://www.amazon.fr/Number-Pi-Pierre-Eymard/dp/0821832468) too.
These books do not deal with the flawed attempts to square the circle, which were countless in history. For this topic, you can consult [Marie Jacob's book](https://www.cairn.info/revue-d-histoire-moderne-et-contemporaine-2009-3-page-212.htm), which is available, I am afraid, only in French.